# Ruby: how to handler thread exception?

Tags: ruby, multithreading, exception

my code here...

```
require 'thread'

$temp = Thread.new do
  loop do
    puts 'loop me'
    begin
      puts "try thread"
      raise Exception.new('QwQ') if rand > 0.5
      puts "skip try"
    rescue
      puts "QwQ"
    end
    sleep(0.5)
  end
  puts '...WTF'
end

loop do
  puts "runner #{Thread.list.length} #{$temp.status}"
  sleep(2)
end
```

how to keep `runner` and `loop thread` running? and how to fix it like this code?

I tried like `Thread.abort_on_exception` , but it will kill the process...

Comment: hmm...... I tried fix all `rescue` to `rescue Exception => e` will be okay , but why!?!?

Comment: okay... I got it , ruby `rescue` default be `StandardError` and `StandardError` super class is `Exception` ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Catch the exception inside the thread, and set the error in a variable accessible by the main thread (for testing you could use a global variable like so: $thread_error).

If the error-variable exists, then raise it from the main thread.

You could also use a queue to communicate between the threads, but then it wouldn't be able to utilize multiple threads.

```
require 'thread'

$temp = Thread.new do
  begin
    loop do
      puts 'loop me'
      begin
        puts "try thread"
        raise Exception.new('QwQ') if rand > 0.5
        puts "skip try"
      rescue
        puts "QwQ"
      end
      sleep(0.5)
    end
    puts '...WTF'
  rescue Exception => e
    $thread_error = e
    raise e
  end
end

loop do
  puts "runner #{Thread.list.length} #{$temp.status}"
  raise $thread_error if $thread_error
  sleep(2)
end
```